# Eslint rules @typescript-eslint/naming-convention conflict with @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm setting up eslint for a typescript project.

this is this rule for unused variables in case of destructuring

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
  "error",
  {
    "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
    "ignoreRestSiblings": true,
    "destructuredArrayIgnorePattern": "^_"
  }
],


//ex:
// error lint
const [a, b] = ['a', 'b']
console.log(b)

// ok
const [_a, b] = ['a', 'b']
console.log(b)
```

but the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule triggers an error. I didn't specify it in the rules but I think it's added with the plugin:"@typescript-eslint" and I didn't want to remove it.

How do I make a rule not interfere with the other? or some way to use the two rules

Comment: Doesn't really help your question, just works around it, but skipping an array destructured value could also be done with a blank element: `const [, b] = ['a', 'b'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`@typescript-eslint/naming-convention`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention) is not usually enabled by default, in any of the configs that `typescript-eslint` comes with. If it is set in your config, you must be extending some other configuration that does enable it.

---

For your specific example, you can skip specific elements in an array destructuring pattern by just putting a comma where the element would be. See the following example from [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
function f() {
  return [1, 2, 3];
}

const [a, , b] = f();
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 3

const [c] = f();
console.log(c); // 1
```

Or in your case:

```
const [, b] = ['a', 'b']
```

---

More generally, however, if you do want to prefix an unused variable with an underscore, there is an option in the `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` rule for that. For example:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "error",
  {
    "selector": "variable",
    "modifiers": ["unused"],
    "format": ["strictCamelCase"],
    "leadingUnderscore": "require"
  },
]
```

Adjust for your own needs. You can make it for other types than just variables, or you don't have to use "strict" camel case (same as camelCase, but consecutive capitals are not allowed [i.e. myId is valid, but myID is not]), or you can make the underscore allowed but not necessarily required. There are even modifiers to make it only apply to destructured variables.

Additionally, I should point out that if this rule was being set from an extended config, then setting it in your own config would override and replace the `naming-convention` rule set in that config, rather than extending it. Any conventions set in the rule from that shared config would not be respected; if you do want to keep them, they would have to be duplicated in your config's `naming-convention` rule, in addition to any modifications you want to make to it.

Comment: that's cool, I think the rule then came from airbnb-typescript. as this is my first eslint file that I configure I ended up that I must have abused the extensions.
I wanted to thank you.. thank you very much